# I am trying to retrieve data from my database using PDO Fetch object

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to retrieve data from my database using PDO Fetch object and it says

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::execute()

what I'm doing wrong
This is what I have tried

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost"; $username = "root"; $password = ""; $dbname = "messages_db";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$getquery = $conn->query('select col_name from db where id = 2');
$getquery->execute();
$result = $getquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
?>

<div><?= $result->col_name; ?></div>
```

Comment: Note that `mysqli` and `PDO` are two different things. You may want to check out the examples in the docs.

Comment: why are you mixing mysqli and PDO?

Comment: `new mysqli(...)` is not a PDO object. You're mixing PDO and mysqli. Pick one.

Comment: Okay I will revise and get that cleared up. Thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, don't mix PDO and mysqli. Stick to one. Here's a PDO example. You first need to create a new PDO object. and connect to DB at the start

```
$servername = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "root";
$dbname = "dbname";

try{
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",$dbusername, 
$dbpassword);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
print "Error! Unable to connect: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
die();
}

$rtrv = "select col_name from db where id = 2"
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($rtrv);
//Execute.
$stmt->execute();

//Fetch.
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// Do whatever you want after this
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It was really helpful. I however edited and used the PDO Fetch Object http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php